# Does Factory Pattern suits the best in my case?

Tags: java, factory

I have a Feeder class that contains a method that feed data into a list, given data, the list and a custom class  :

```
default void feedData(CustomData myData, List list, Class c){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if(myData!= null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> map : myData.getData()) {
            list.add(objectMapper.convertValue(map, c));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement a design pattern because I have several classes that can should feed data regarding specific classes.
I thought about Factory pattern, is that a good idea?

Class 1 would be like:

```
public void feed(CustomData myData){
    feedData(myData, myField, CustomClass1.class);
}
```

Class 2 :

```
public void feed(CustomData myData){
    feedData(myData, myField2, CustomClass2.class);
}
```

etc.

And then, an interface for example IFeeder where I declare

```
void feed(CustomData myData);
```

But where can I put the `feedData` method? Inside this interface?

If yes, I should declare it as default, but default keyword is for a default method that return always the same result, isn't it?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Factory is a creational DP though, you need a structural DP something like facade-pattern

Comment: you can refer this https://www.javatpoint.com/facade-pattern

Comment: Thanks it really helps. But in this example, for the interface what about my feedData method? Should I put it in the interface too, as default ? I don't get it

Comment: For an example of using the Factory, check out ServerSocketEx.SocketHandlerFactory here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java. SocketServers accept new connections, and then these connections need to handled. ServerSocketEx as a way to automatically create a handler and start it when there's a new connection. But the factory is flexible enough to allow you to create a subclass which provides custom ServerSocketRunners

Comment: Sidenote: (Maybe a micro-optimization) You create the ObjectMapper outside the if. That means you create the object regardless of if it will be actually used or not. I'd either inject it or at least create it inside the if.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T>  void  feedData(CustomData myData, List<T> list, Class<T> clazz){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if(myData!= null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> map : myData.getData()) {
            list.add(objectMapper.convertValue(map, clazz));
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this should work. This can be a static method in some util class.

I am assuming that all the other classes that you are referring can implement a common interface.